# Challenge PHP with strcmp

Tags: php, logic

I'm trying to do this challenges PHP / logic and hacking. I have to do to print the page "Success" finding the password to this page http://leggend.orgfree.com/index.php/challenge/strcmp.php, when I find I have to add passwords to the password in the URL like this:
http://leggend.orgfree.com/index.php/chall...mp.php?psw=PASSWORD
The password (I think this) is in password.php etc.  but if you go in password.php go in the site of challenges.  
I've found with psw = 00 but not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as
http://leggend.orgfree.com/index.php/challenge/strcmp.php?psw[]=
And that do the trick

Functions in PHP return NULL when they receive wrong type of arguments. In case of strcmp both arguments must be string. I'm passing variable as "psw[]" in that case it become array. So arguments of strcmp is **Array** and **String** and function return NULL. Then there is check **==** in case of different types there is happens typecasting and NULL == 0 returns true. To fix that is simply need replace **==** with **===** or check type of input arguments. So fixed code looks like:

```
$correctPassword = include "password.php";
if (isset($_GET["psw"]) && strcmp($_GET["psw"], $correctPassword) === 0) {
    echo "Successo!";
}
```

Comment: Can I know what you have use? Step for step

Comment: @WhileNext i'm updated my answer with explanation why it works and how to fix

Comment: Thanks, Can I ask how to Can I study PHP?

Comment: Read docs on http://php.net or watch one of courses from lynda or treehouse or whatever to get start. Then do a lot of code, the better way to study something is to use it.